# Start stop Service from Form App c#

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

How can I start and stop a windows service from a c# Form application?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Add a reference to `System.ServiceProcess.dll`.  Then you can use the [ServiceController](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yb9w7ytd) class.

```
// Check whether the Alerter service is started.
ServiceController sc  = new ServiceController();
sc.ServiceName = "Alerter";
Console.WriteLine("The Alerter service status is currently set to {0}", 
                   sc.Status.ToString());

if (sc.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped)
{
   // Start the service if the current status is stopped.
   Console.WriteLine("Starting the Alerter service...");
   try 
   {
      // Start the service, and wait until its status is "Running".
      sc.Start();
      sc.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running);

      // Display the current service status.
      Console.WriteLine("The Alerter service status is now set to {0}.", 
                         sc.Status.ToString());
   }
   catch (InvalidOperationException)
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Could not start the Alerter service.");
   }
}
```

Comment: this only starts the service

Answer (score 31):

First add a reference to the System.ServiceProcess assembly.

To start:

```
ServiceController service = new ServiceController("YourServiceName");
service.Start();
var timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5); // 5seconds
service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running, timeout);
```

To stop:

```
ServiceController service = new ServiceController("YourServiceName");
service.Stop();
 var timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5); // 5seconds
service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped, timeout);
```

Both examples show how to wait until the service has reached a new status (running, stopped...etc.). The timeout parameter in WaitForStatus is optional.

Comment: it doesn't recognize this using System.ServiceProcess; - i'm using .net 4

Comment: Should work fine, but you have to add a reference to System.ServiceProcess.

Comment: It is throwing me an Invalide Operation Exception

Comment: Please note that "Service name" and "Display name" can be different for a Windows Service e.g. for IIS service, the "Service name" is `W3SVC` while its "Display name" is `World Wide Web Publishing Service`.  We should provide "Service name" in the code snippet shown in the post.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this, [Details of Service Controller](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.aspx)

```
ServiceController sc = new ServiceController("your service name");
if (sc.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped)
{
  sc.Start();

}
```

Similarly you can stop using stop method

```
  sc.Stop();
```

Comment: it doesn't recognize this using System.ServiceProcess; - i'm using .net 4

Comment: Add the namespace, probably your are missing it.

Answer (score 3):

there is a dirtier, but same same..
just execute the shell command

```
NET STOP "MYSERVICENAME"
NET START "MYSERVICENAME"
```

EDIT:
Would like to expand on "dirtier":
 1. it is slower.
 2. this can result in some clever vulnerabilities
 3. it is a code that is not "understandable"
 4. it is highly not portable (surely if you use .NET Core)

I am sure there are more wrong with it...
but if you search for a small, inhouse tool... it'll do.
(would like to say temporary, but temp stuff stick best!)

Answer (score 0):

```
// Check whether the U-TEST RTC service is started.
        ServiceController sc = new ServiceController();
        sc.ServiceName = "U-TEST RTC";
        m_objMainChainRTC.m_objUC.ValidationLogMessages(String.Format(LocalizeDictionary.Instance.GetLocalizedValue("MsgStatusService"), sc.Status.ToString()), Alstom.Automation.Forms.ViewModels.RTCAutomationViewModel.ColorLog.Log);

        if (sc.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped)
        {
            m_objMainChainRTC.m_objUC.ValidationLogMessages(String.Format(LocalizeDictionary.Instance.GetLocalizedValue("MsgStartService")), Alstom.Automation.Forms.ViewModels.RTCAutomationViewModel.ColorLog.Log);
            try
            {
                // Start the service, and wait until its status is "Running".
                sc.Start();
                var timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5); // 5seconds
                sc.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running, timeout);
                m_objMainChainRTC.m_objUC.ValidationLogMessages(String.Format(LocalizeDictionary.Instance.GetLocalizedValue("MsgNowService"), sc.Status.ToString()), Alstom.Automation.Forms.ViewModels.RTCAutomationViewModel.ColorLog.Log);
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException)
            {
                m_objMainChainRTC.m_objUC.ValidationLogMessages(String.Format(LocalizeDictionary.Instance.GetLocalizedValue("MsgExceptionStartService")), Alstom.Automation.Forms.ViewModels.RTCAutomationViewModel.ColorLog.Log);
            }
        }
```