# Trying to complete multiple operations in a single button click

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I've been using Stackoverflow to build this application and everything as been going great, thanks to all the helpful posts out there.

ErrorFixClick is the one button I'm getting stuck on. I want to put multiple operations within a single button click.

Here is the code I've cobbled together. Is it pretty code, no. Could it be written much better, of course! Does it work? Something do when run as an individual button event, but combined it doesn't work.

I've not taken a C# class in a decade and I could use some help. I've added some notes to the code for each operation to make it a bit easier to understand

Thanks in advance.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.IO;

namespace SuperDupperDesktopApp
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


    }

    private void StartME_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Process.Start("C:\\Program Files\\OSE\\StartME.exe");
    }
    private void Reboot_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Process.Start("shutdown.exe", "-r -t 05 -f");
    }
    private void Info_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string hostname = System.Environment.MachineName;

        MessageBox.Show(Environment.OSVersion.ToString());
        MessageBox.Show(hostname);

    }


    private void ErrorFix_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) // <-- This is broken.
    {

        /// Stop a service
        Process cmd = new Process();
        cmd.StartInfo.FileName = @"cmd.exe";
        cmd.StartInfo.Arguments = @"/c SC STOP COMSVCS"; 
        cmd.Start();
        cmd.WaitForExit();

        ///Delete a file
        if (File.Exists(@"C:\op\cp.dat"))
        {
            File.Delete(@"C:\op\cp.dat");
        }

        /// Kill the App
        foreach (var process in Process.GetProcessesByName("StartME"))
        {
            process.Kill();
        }

        /// Reboot the PC
        Process.Start("shutdown.exe", "-r -t 01 -f");

    }
}
```

Comment: what is meant by not working here, any exception coming or what ?

Comment: When I run the app and press the ErrorFix_Click Button Event, no errors and no actions.

Comment: Microsoft (R) Roslyn C# Compiler version 2.1.0.61520
Loading context from 'CSharpInteractive.rsp'.
Type "#help" for more information.
>         private void ErrorFix_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) // <-- This is broken.
. 
(1,69): error CS1002: ; expected
>

Comment: Using ErrorFix_Click - If i comment out the stop a service code and run the remaining portion of code in interactive mode it works. Running it compiled without the stop service code It doesn't run.

Comment: Learn to use a debugger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest switching your service stopping to use the library functions instead of starting another process:

[Start stop Service from Form App c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11062841/start-stop-service-from-form-app-c-sharp)