# Run a batch file with powershell in it and failing

Tags: c#, powershell, batch-file

I have a batch file with the following content

```
@powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -Command "Start-Process secondBat.bat -Verb runas"
```

secondBat.bat has the following

```
sc stop theService
pause
```

I tried to run this batch file (the first one) with

```
int exitCode;
    var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/C " + @"c:\FirstBat.bat");
    processInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    Process process = Process.Start(processInfo);
    process.WaitForExit();
    exitCode = process.ExitCode;
    process.Close();
```

The exitCode I got was "1" (so a failure) and the batch file (and the contents) did not execute properly.

I don't know powershell at all, so I would appreciate a pointer here. What am i doing wrong?

EDIT: I commented the `processInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;` and now I can see the message
"the command cannot be run due to the error the system cannot find the file specified"

Comment: turn on the window, .. why would you call a .bat file wto call powershell, why not have it as powershell. As a point "runas" runas what? it doesnt seem to answer that question.. if all you're wanting is to stop a service.

Comment: Could you elaborate. I turned on the window and used Shell execute and I got some message in red in the window that dissapeared. Still the service is still running. Apparetnly the system can not find the file specified. But I tried the bat manually and it worked

Comment: SO dont use /c to terminate it - you need to read what it said...

Comment: When I eliminate the /c the system waits for ever.

Comment: and you get to read the red portion...

Comment: Ok so it cant find the second batch file, just cos you ran c:\firstbat.bat where is secondbat? you havent set a working directroy.. so it will look where you are..

Comment: Thank you! I think that is it!

Comment: You probably could have avoided a lot of mess with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11062841/start-stop-service-from-form-app-c-sharp

Comment: Well, I tried that. Unfortunately that requires administrator permissions, otherwise you get an exception -as I did.

Comment: If that's all there is inside your batch file, because `SC.exe` is a stand-alone executable, you probably don't need a batch file at all, just use `Start-Process` with `SC.exe`. You could perhaps also consider stopping the service using the `Stop-Service` cmdlet in `PowerShell`.

Comment: TBH @KansaiRobot you never mentioned getting an exception

Comment: As an expansion of my last comment, you could get rid of `secondBat.bat` and use this in `FirstBat.bat`: `@PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command "Start-Process -FilePath 'sc.exe' -Verb runAs -ArgumentList 'Stop ServiceName'"` where you'd obviously replace `ServiceName` with the name of the service you need to stop. That said, there should be no need to use either of the batch files or powershell! You should be able to stop the service directly from C#, even including runas directly inside it to elevate that specific command only.

Comment: @Compo Thanks for your comment. About the last part, I have been trying to do that too, but it need administrator rights. You said "runas directly inside it to elevate that command only". Could you elaborate more on that please

Answer (score 2):

Problem boiled down to running before walking.

1. Dont dismiss windows which may show messages you need until you get it all working
2. On finding the error "file not found" but see it, its not looking where you do

Solution:

Always add a working path  The more specific you are with everything the harder it is for it to pick the wrong thing.  So in this case

```
processInfo.WorkingFolder = @"c:\";
```

Other options, could probably have done it direct in C# or 1 batch file.