# How to call Powershell command from ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, powershell, asp.net-web-api

I am using System.Management.Automation.dll to call powershell command from ASP.NET WebAPI.
I am trying to start and stop windows service form ASP.NET WebAPI on demand.
On my local machine it is working fine.

But when I call API to either to start or stop windows service it is giving me following error,
**Cannot find any service with service name 'Log Reader'.**

Following command are being use,

```
Start-Service -Name 'Log Reader' -Verbose
Stop-Service -Name 'Log Reader' -Verbose
```

My code is, filename is the name of powershell command file,

```
      var runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();

            runspace.Open();
            var ps = PowerShell.Create();
            ps.Runspace = runspace;
            
            string script = GetScript(status, fileName);
            ps.Commands.AddScript(script);

            var result = ps.Invoke();
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (var r in result)
            {
                sb.Append(r.ToString());
                sb.Append("\n");
            }
            sb.Remove(0, sb.Length);
            foreach (var error in ps.Streams.Error.ReadAll())
            {
                sb.Append(error.ToString());
                sb.Append("\n");
            }
            runspace.Close();
```

Here, I am using Service Account as application pool identity.Windows service is also calling some commands using powershell and it is executed perfectly under same service account.

I think it might be related to IIS. Please help me.

Comment: If all you're doing is stopping / starting a service, you don't need to call a PowerShell script at all - you can use the ServiceController class in C# - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11062841/start-stop-service-from-form-app-c-sharp. If you still desperately want to use PowerShell, try running the script on the server in an interactive console to make sure it works there first - you might find the issue is in the script rather than the way you're calling it.

Answer (score 0):

There was Access right issue with app pool user.Once it is given I am able to call Windows Service.

Comment: This weakens security. You now run the risk of a hacker executing a malicious script. You should use ServiceController instead, or use WMI