# How to start SQL Server service use with C# code?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Currently I have some client's PC as a Windows 11 user, so if the services in SQL Server are stopped, can anyone suggest how I can check it, and how to start the service, also through C# code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Start stop Service from Form App c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11062841/start-stop-service-from-form-app-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

if your service name is different, write your instead of "SQLEXPRESS".

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = "net start \"Sql Server (SQLEXPRESS)\"";
process.Start();
```

or

```
ServiceController service = new ServiceController("SQLEXPRESS");
service.Start();
```

If you want to start the service after checking that it has stopped ;

```
ServiceController service = new ServiceController("SQLEXPRESS");

if (service .Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped)
{
  service.Start();
}
```

Comment: Tried all three of my solutions but it didn't work, I'm using SQL Server 2005 or Visual Studio 2008